# Find disk usage by topic in a Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a Kafka monitoring metrics, a Java API, or a JMX bean to obtain the disk usage per topic in a Kafka cluster?

Is there a way to determine the total disk usage by the cluster including all topics/partitions/replicas?

Comment: I don't think there is since it would be inconsistent between multiple replicas and you cannot guarantee the leader broker will have a complete snapshot of the data in the event of a failover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is available from Kafka version 1.1 through the `AdminClient API` method `describeLogDirs()`. By iterating through a series of nested maps for brokers -> paths-> topic-partitions -> replicas, you can get the size for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value with the following JMX

```
kafka.log.Log.value:name=size
```

There are other metrics also available depending on your requirement the query can be changed